# Wordpress Align Button Not Working

Tags: css, wordpress, text-align

I got this problem when migration from Shared Hosting to VPS. The problem is Align Button not working when i write article on Wordpress. When i press it, the position (Align Left - Center - Right - Justify) Not Working, nothing happend.

[image: WP Align Button]

Im tried put this code on WP Stylesheet, but align button still not working.

```
img.alignright { float: right; margin: 0 0 1em 1em; }
img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
img.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.alignright { float: right; }
.alignleft { float: left; }
.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

please help me thanks,

Comment: There's no way we can address this; no website to check, no code to look at, nothing. How do you expect us to help with this? The type of hosting shouldn't matter one bit, btw. On the other hand, the proper css attribute is `text-align: left / center / right / justify` Also, are you getting any errors in the console? When you look at the source code, can you see the `<p>` and inline style?

Comment: The floats in your CSS won't have the desired effect - they affect the whole container, not its contents. So instead of `float: left` you should use `text-align: left` ( and similar for the other alignments) in there. However, if this alone will solve your problem is hard to say (actually I doubt it), since obviously there are some more complex CSS rules in your code (which you didn't post) that prevent the default alignments.

Answer (score 0):

This is happend when i use Mozila Firefox.
I still do not know what causes it, but when I change use other browser ( Opera ) it's work perfectly.

Problem Solved, try **Use Other Browser**.

may be this will help people who will face the same problem in WP.